# Copying and pasting image from clipboard to rich text editor

Tags: sharepoint-online, rich-text, image-upload, image-rendition

Attachment in SharePoint works, but copy paste image from clipboard to rich text editor does not works. Is there a way to copy and paste an image from clipboard to the enhanced text box? It will be okay even if we need to use a third party plugin.

Comment: Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I can copy image from Paint and past it to the rich text editor. But it will not save the image after saving.  When I go to edit the item, there is no image in the rich text editor. It does not support copying and pasting image to rich text editor by default.
There is workaround. You could copy the image and paste to the Paint, then save it as a picture. And upload the picture to the rich text editor.

Comment: @Amy Thank you Amy. This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Amy_MSFT, this is the exact behavior I am seeing.  I can paste but the image does not save.  I agree with Dilip, though.  This is not an acceptable work-around.  I want things to be as easy as possible for my users.  They are much more likely to upload an image with a bug report if they can simply paste it.